# Text under the button flutter

Tags: flutter

this is the code:

```dart
class DocClinVisi extends StatelessWidget {
  const DocClinVisi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){},
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        height: 110,
        width: 110,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          ),
        child: Image.asset('imagens/frame-1.png'),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the text is under the button, or that you want the text to be under the button

Comment: text under the button, outside the button

Comment: But are you asking how to do that, or are you complaining that the text is currently there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to show text "outside" the button.
If you need to "float" text outside the container you can use Stack:

```dart
class DocClinVisi extends StatelessWidget {
  const DocClinVisi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            height: 110,
            width: 110,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
          ),
          const Positioned(
            bottom: -20,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Text('Hello World', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note that this method could overlap the text with other widgets in some cases.
If you need to make the text part of the widget so it will not overlap, you could replace Stack for a Column:

```dart
class DocClinVisi extends StatelessWidget {
  const DocClinVisi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            height: 110,
            width: 110,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
          ),
          const Text('Hello World', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your container with column, then set text below the container, you can see and copy paste code below:

```
class DocClinVisi extends StatelessWidget {
  const DocClinVisi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){},
      child: Column( // add column
        children: [
           Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              height: 110,
              width: 110,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              child: Image.asset('imagens/frame-1.png'),
           ),
          Text('My Button'), // then add the text
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```